# Discord.js - guild.member.get returning undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've tried a lot of different methods of doing this.
But I keep running into an issue where the user is returning undefined.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined

`code[1]` is a discord id that I am passing through an embed which the bot is reading.
The method I am trying at the moment, is getting the guild by id, then the member by id. I did try message.guild but I was getting the same issue.

When this runs on my ID, the add roll works. However, when other members try, it returns undefined.
Am I getting the member wrong?

```
var code = message.embeds[0].title.split( ":" );

let user_guilds = client.guilds.get( "453314772662878211" );
let user_member = user_guilds.members.get( code[1] );
    
user_member.addRole('455695410401640449');
```

Hopefully someone knows discord.js better than I do and can tell me what I'm doing wrong haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with Discord.js version v12 it works diferent: addRole now is `member.roles.add("role id ")`

```js
user_member.roles.add('roleid');
```

Comment: I was still using v11.
Somehow, updating fixed my issue.